myfaces 3.x selectOneRadio generates the html input with id being included in the value
I have this selectOneRadio element in my xhtml page.
<h:selectOneRadio id="deliveryMethodEInvoice" group="deliveryMethod" value="#{eInvoiceSignUpBean.deliveryMethod}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="" />
</h:selectOneRadio>

It generates the html input below.  Everything looks fine, except the value of this input element.  I am expecting the value to be 1, but it is eInvoiceSignUpForm:deliveryMethodEInvoice:1.  Is this normal?  Somehow the backend bean is works correctly because it is getting the value of 1.  But the xhtml page has some javascript that do some simple validation before submitting the form.  The javascirpt is erroring out the request because it is expecting the value of 1.
<input id="eInvoiceSignUpForm:deliveryMethodEInvoice" type="radio" name="eInvoiceSignUpForm:deliveryMethod" value="eInvoiceSignUpForm:deliveryMethodEInvoice:1">


